# History not fully deleted using chrome.history.deleteRange

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I have written a small extension that uses `deleteRange` from `chrome.history` API in order to delete parts of the browser history between a start and an end time stamp.

```
chrome.history.deleteRange({
   startTime : startTime,
   endTime : endTime
}, function() {
   console.log("Recent history deleted successfully");
});
```

I get both `startTime` and `endTime` using `(new Date()).getTime()`.

It "kind of works". If I open a page in Chrome for the very first time after starting the extension, I will be able to use its URL in the omnibox without fully typing it (a sign for me that Chrome remembers the URL through its history). After calling `deleteRange`, I am no longer able to do so. I also see the text `Recent history deleted successfully` on the console. This is a sign for me that the page has been wiped from history.

But it hasn't. If I go to Chrome/Settings/History, I can still see when I accessed the page. I expected that this would have been wiped ... how can I wipe a page (that I never ever opened before) from the recent history using start and end time stamp?

EDIT: I added the line

```
console.log("Right before calling deleteRange. startTime=" + startTime + " / endTime=" + endTime);
```

to my code which resulted in

```
Right before calling deleteRange. startTime=1416931451880 / endTime=1416931463988
```

EDIT2: I opened a [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436492). Let's see what I can get from there

Comment: I would assume that the access time of the entry in question needs to lie between `startTime` and `endTime`. What happens when you expand the range, and don't use the same exact time for both (or am I misunderstanding how you set them)?

Comment: I am using the same code to set startTime and endTime, but I use it at two different points of time (two different clicks on the browser action icon), so they are different and the page visit is clearly between startTime and endTime)

Comment: Can you add the console output showing the 3 times being set?

Comment: What about the page access time?

Comment: How should I find this? I just manually opened a page between startTime and endTime. I can see it in Settings/History (with local time hours/minutes), so the visit has been automatically recorded

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but there appears to be a [`visitTime` property](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) that you should be able to access somehow.

Comment: Ok, I used `chrome.history.search` to get the visits to this URL. There is only one visit. The data is `startTime= 1416935533132 / endTime= 1416935581284 / lastVisitTime= 1416935539946.32`

Comment: ... and after the call to `chrome.history.deleteRange` this visit has disappeared (i.e. is not available in chrome.history.search any more, but still visible in Chrome/Settings/History)

Comment: I have opened a Chromium bug on https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436492 and will offer a bounty as soon as it's available

Comment: Bug has been confirmed if history sync is enabled ... so bounty will expire unused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium developers have confirmed the bug. It depends on History Sync being enabled.

See [Chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation: [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-deleteRange)

It states, that:

> Pages will not be removed from the history unless **ALL** visits fall
>   within the range.

So my guess is, that those pages you get suggestions for, have visits from before startTime. So their URLs aren't removed, because not all visits fall within the range you specify.

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not it. As described above I visited the page for the very first time. There has been no other visit. In the meantime the bug has been confirmed by Chromium developers. It depends on History Sync being enabled.

Comment: @devnull69 You should post a self-answer explaining that it's a known bug that has to do with History sync